# Can unique_ptr point to a normal pointer?

Tags: c++

c++ primer fifth edition says：

> Unlike shared_ptr,there is no library function comparable to make_shared that return a unique_ptr.Instead,when wo define a unique_ptr,we bind it to a pointer returned bu *new*.

But the following code can compile and run.why?

```
int ix = 1024, * pi = &ix;
unique_ptr<int> uq1(pi);
```

Comment: std::make_unique exists I think but in C++ 14. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: A "normal pointer" is what points at the thing that's `new`ed, so it's hardly a contradiction. Just further demonstrates why raw pointers can be problematic on their own.

Comment: C++ Primer seems to be focused on C++ 11.

Comment: In the case of the code you show: Then no it won't work. `std::unique_ptr` wants to get a total and complete ownership of the data being pointed to. By passing it a pointer to an object that is managed by the compiler it can't do that.

Comment: Even though this will compile as soon as the `unique_ptr` goes out out of scope and get destroyed lots of hilarity will ensue.

Comment: The following code also compiles: `int ix = 1024, *pi = &ix; delete pi;`. But it's equally wrong.

Comment: I think C++ Primer talks about the omission of `std::make_unique` in C++11 (it did introduce `std::make_shared`). If you read it in the sense of "it's your own responsibility to set up a pointer and pass it to `std::unique_ptr`", there's no contradiction. It never says it wouldn't compile. You can compile a lot of things in C++ that won't work.

Comment: A note of warning: Just because something compiles cleanly without errors or even warnings (even with extra warning enabled, which you should always do), doesn't mean the code is actually correct. Yes it might follow all the syntactic and semantic rules that the compiler checks for, but you might still do bad things like attempting to `delete &ix` (which is basically what will happen with your code). Your code will lead to *undefined behavior*, which is a main source of crashes or other bad behavior in programs.

Comment: How do you think a compiler can tell the difference (in general) between a pointer allocated with `new` and a regular pointer? A moments thought should tell you that it cannot (e.g. `int x; int *p = random ? &x : new int;` whether `p` is pointed to `new` allocated data or not depends on the value of `random`, which presumably is random). Therefore the compiler cannot implement the suggestion you are making, because it cannot tell the difference between the two kinds of pointers.

Comment: The reason that your code runs, despite the error, is because of *undefined behaviour*. Your code has undefined behaviour and one possible outcome from undefined behaviour is running without error.

Comment: *But the following code can compile and run.why?*  Because C++ is not a nanny language.  It expects the programmer to provide correct & valid code.  Unfortunately, in practice, that's a pretty high bar.  The language gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can unique_ptr point to a normal pointer?

Yes they can. Though usually they point to dynamically allocated objects that are not themselves pointers (rarely it makes sense to dynamically allocate a pointer). Smart pointers do this by encapsulating a raw pointer to that object. Though that's just nitpicking on wording of your title, so please read on.

Your code is no contradiction to the statement you are quoting. Though, the code is wrong.

Consider what happens when the variables go out of scope:

```
{
    int ix = 1024, * pi = &ix;
    std::unique_ptr<int> uq1(pi);
} // <-
```

At the end of the scope, first `uq1` will be destroyed. Internally, it calls `delete` on the pointer. That is undefined behavior, because you can only `delete` an object that has been created via `new`.

Prior to C++14, the corrected code would be:

```
{
    int* pi = new int(1024);
    std::unique_ptr<int> uq1(pi);
}
```

`pi` points to dynamically allocated `int`. The ownership is transferred to the smart pointer, which then calls `delete` when it is destructed.

Doing it like above, by explicitly calling `new` has several downsides. For example, it is inconsistent with `std::make_shared()` that returns a `std::shared_ptr`. In C++14, `std::make_unique()` was introduced:

```
{
    auto uq1 = std::make_unique<int>(1042);
}
```

The text you quote refers to a time before C++14, when there was "no library function comparable to make_shared that return a unique_ptr." (sic)

Comment: Just an FYI, "*Smart pointers point to dynamically allocated objects*" - is a little narrow-sighted, because they can actually point at any resource that can be "deleted", not just dynamic objects. The *default behavior* you describe relies on the `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` operators, yes, but that can be tweaked by providing a smart pointer with a custom `deleter` (ie, to free a file handle, or release some OS resource/memory, etc). So, smart pointers are more flexible than you have described. Though, their *primary* usage is to manage the lifetime of a dynamic object, yes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good point. Not what I actually wanted to say, but poor wording. I tried to refer to the "usual case" (which is waht OP refers to) rather than giving the expression to explain them as a whole